# Where do the candidates of "Naked and Afraid" get salt?

Tags: naked-and-afraid

"Naked and Afraid" is a Discovery Channel survival show, where a group of people survive for 21 or 40 days without any clothes or food.

They could find food by hunting, but where do they get salt for food?

By salt, I mean "white powder" salt or any other forms of sodium chloride that could provide the same functionality.

They are not next to a shore. They are in the Amazon jungle or Solani River Basin.

They did get an impala which suffice their need for protein, and bundles of wild spinach.

Comment: What kind of salt do you mean? If it's "white powder" salt, they could evaporate some saltwater (were they next to a shore?). Or if you meant salt as a nutriment such as carbs, protein and all, there is salt in the stuff one eats already.

Comment: @Jenayah Yes, it's "white powder" salt or any other forms of sodium chloride that could provide the same functionality. They are not next to a shore. They are in amazon jungle or Solani River Basin.

Comment: Why do they need **additional** salt? As Jenayah said, it's in most foodstuffs naurally.

Comment: What would they need salt for?

Comment: @TK-421 The weather is hot, they sweat a lot.

Comment: I would be much more concerned with other necessary nutritious elements to survive.

Comment: @TK-421 such as?

Comment: Vitamins, proteins if they can't get any meat to eat, and so on.

Comment: They did get an impala and bundles of wild spinach, and some other animals.

Comment: Personally I'm not following your question. Are you talking about a specific episode where you noticed they had salt but no explanation for where it came from? Or are you assuming they have this one resource replenished for whatever production reason on every episode? As far as I can tell - assuming the show is legitimate - they never have anything except what is explained in the episode be it brought, provided or found. The answer then is as many suggest: they just don't have salt.

Comment: @KaiQing  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my comment:
Personally I'm not following your question. Are you talking about a specific episode where you noticed they had salt but no explanation for where it came from? Or are you assuming they have this one resource replenished for whatever production reason on every episode? As far as I can tell - assuming the show is legitimate - they never have anything except what is explained in the episode be it brought, provided or found. The answer then is as many suggest: they just don't have salt.

To further the comment, the show is interesting in providing a comparable survival experience in many harsh environments. Some get a land of fruit, water, fish and more. Some get a hot barren desert. One episode, a guy was kicked off for trying to secretly raid the crew's snack pile. I don't have a lot of confidence reality TV isn't guided and to some degree a straight up lie. But Naked and Afraid has never given me the impression it isn't largely legitimate from the perspective of survival and resources... the bickering... some of that may be prodded by the producers. I've worked with some people who have been on the production crew of some reality TV shows and they say they range from complete lies to a normal scenario where the producers give them subjects to argue about. Fabricated drama, as it were. Because drama gets ratings.

From what I've seen on the show, I don't think the producers are stepping in with condiments or seasonings. I think they want the raw reactions of eating things like snakes, insects, and other vile things without the benefit of masking the atrocious taste. It makes for better television that way and costs less. Win win for the producers.

Answer (score -2):

Your question makes perfect sense. Anyone that has ever just eaten greens/leaves and olive oil before (vegan ketogenic) knows that sodium levels drop quickly. It leaves you lethargic, weak, dizzy which worsens if stand, insomniac, and sick - especially if you're outside sweating a lot. In fact, I feel most tap-outs are caused by low sodium, not dehydration or low protein.

Initially, you can go a while without protein. When the body breaks down fat, critical amino acids get recycled. My record is 2 months without eating protein - it depends how fat you are.

Marathon runners who die from heart attacks are mostly people who sweat, drink too much water, and don't replenish salt.

In fact, the word "salad" comes from the latin "sal", which means salt. The ancients knew you needed to add salt to leaves to survive.

No-one on the show drinks seawater for some reason, even though a 1/2 cup contains your daily 2000 mg sodium and water requirements (that 8 glasses per day is a total myth).

But to answer your question: [**it's fake**. They get everything they need from the producers, or they steal it from a nearby crew tent.](https://www.thetalko.com/things-on-naked-and-afraid-that-are-totally-fake-and-that-are-legit/amp/).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Movies & TV.  If you're want to argue that the producers supply things to the contestants then you need to lead with that and include some quotes instead of just a link.  You can also leave out the discursion on the effects of insufficient salt, since that isn't actually relevant to the answer.

Comment: i answered the first guys question, where do contestants get salt… from the producers. then i answered everyone else who was confused as to y the contestants needed salt to survive

Comment: "No-one on the show drinks seawater for some reason, even though a 1/2 cup contains your daily 2000 mg sodium and water requirements" I'm trying to think of some way this could be a typo, or that a person with basic understanding of human physiology could actually believe it, and I'm having trouble making sense of either hypothesis. When people say that 8 glasses a day is a myth, they're saying it's **too low**, especially for someone engaging in significant exercise. Are you seriously going an entire day drinking nothing but a juice box?